# Active link in the navigation list

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have separate file (LIB.php) with defined function. 
This function is called in each page.
I want to make it dynamic, when I navigate to one of the pages the page gets active state in the

```
function get_Navigation(){

$navigation = <<<END
 <div class="menubar">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i><main>Home</main></a></li>
      <li><a href="admin.php"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i><main>Admin</main></a></li>
      <li><a href="cart.php"><i class="icon-money icon-large"></i><main>Cart</main></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
END;

echo $navigation;
}
```

Comment: You can use `__FILE__` to get the current file and check if it is the same as the file in the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to get the file name, this will return something like `index.php` then, you can add a class to the row or the link to modify its appearance. So your code could look something like this if you want to keep using the [heredoc string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead of concatenating several strings:

```
$isactive = "isactive";
function isactive($filename){
    $currentfile = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    if($currentfile == $filename) return "active";
}
$navigation = <<<END
 <div class="menubar">

    <ul>
      <li class='{$isactive("prog.php")}'><a href="index.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i><main>Home</main></a></li>
      <li class='{$isactive("admin.php")}'><a href="admin.php"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i><main>Admin</main></a></li>
      <li class='{$isactive("cart.php")}'><a href="cart.php"><i class="icon-money icon-large"></i><main>Cart</main></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
END;

echo $navigation;
```

Note that I'm creating a `$isactive` variable which may seem redundant but it's a way of tricking heredoc string to return the functions value instead of just printing its name, but this is really on another scope.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on do you use any framework and are you rewriting the URLs. If we assume that its about plain old PHP without rewrites, you can do something like:

```
function get_Navigation(){

   $current_filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
   $menuItems = array('index' => false, 'admin' => false, 'cart' => false);

   switch($current_filename) {
      case 'index': $menuItems['index'] = true; break;
      case 'admin': $menuItems['admin'] = true; break;
      case 'cart': $menuItems['cart'] = true; break;
   }

   $navigation = '
      <div class="menubar">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="index.php" class="' . ($menuItems['index'] ? 'selected' : '') . '"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i><main>Home</main></a></li>
         <li><a href="admin.php" class="' . ($menuItems['admin'] ? 'selected' : '') . '"><i class="icon-star icon-large"></i><main>Admin</main></a></li>
         <li><a href="cart.php" class="' . ($menuItems['cart'] ? 'selected' : '') . '"><i class="icon-money icon-large"></i><main>Cart</main></a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
';

   echo $navigation;
}
```

I'm assuming the index page is named index.php, the admin page - admin.php and the cart page - cart.php

This will append class 'selected' to the active a link.